# Creating a Telegram bot using botpress

Tags: heroku, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Hey I am using botpress to create a Telegram bot.

I did all the required steps:

1. Created a bot that works locally also after updating my code at localhost:3000
2. I deployed the code to heroku with your docs and it works
3. I got an access token from botfather and added it to the botfile.js

The one thing that I could not find is the step of connecting the heroku to telegram.

Did someone has an experience with that or even just a telegram bot in heroku that worked?